# The term 'protractor' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: protractor

I have installed protractor using the command:

```
npm install --save-dev protractor
```

and i can see the path `node_modules\protractor\bin` which includes `protractor` file. But, when i use the visual code Termainal to run the `protractor --version` command, it complains with:

```
protractor : The term 'protractor' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ protractor --version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (protractor:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I tried to navigate into the `protractor/bin` and then run again, but the result is still the same

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "protractor-learning",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jasmin": "0.0.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  }
}
```

if i use `npm install -g --save-dev protractor` then i have the protractor command line, but it is not registered in my `package.json`

Comment: probably because you installed protractor locally, but trying execute it globally, try `./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor --version` or install it globally first

Comment: Checkout setup section https://www.protractortest.org/#/

Comment: @LuninRoman please check my update

Comment: You use wrong path of the `protractor` executable binary,  it should be `.\node_modules\.bin\protractor`, instead of `./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor`

Answer (score 0):

This usually happen when you open Two windows of Visual Studio Code and run '`protractor config.js`' command in terminal. Try running in one window of VS and see if it still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to current user having an undefined ExecutionPolicy. And this was resolved after executing the below command in TERMINAL.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Answer (score 0):

If you Run visual code as administrator and then hit the command in Visual code terminal, it should work. I was also facing the same issue and it worked after launching the Visual code as administrator.

Comment: Generally, I would advise against running anything as Admin/root unless absolutely necessary